# Trouble with Weka's logistic regression (objective function NaN)

Tags: machine-learning, weka

so I'm trying to use logistic regression in Weka.  I have a large training and test set 25,000 instances / 5,000 instances, and both have an equal number of class A and class B in them.  When I run logistic regression, it gives me the message "Objective function NaN", and I'm not sure what this means or how to fix it.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How are you executing WEKA? Command line or did you write your own Java code? Please post the command you executed / the relevant code parts, otherwise helping you will be difficult.